# jQuery .slideDown executes twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, slidedown, document-ready

I'm new to jquery and bumped into a problem i can't fix

I want that on pageload my content is sliding down so i use the next code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").hide();
    $("#content").slideDown(1000);
  });
```

when i load the page the content slides down narmally, than the content gets hidden and slides down again.

When i go to the css and do `#content{display: none;}` instead of `$("#content").hide();` everything works fine. (can't use this for browsers without js)

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that isn't called twice? I just made a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/qKUQ4/

Comment: your code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/kN8Mf/ Is there something else that should affect it?

Comment: I explect this might be a browser specific bug - what is your platform/browser?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that everything works fine while using css `#content{display: none;}`
than i offer u to use Jquery .css() method( http://api.jquery.com/css/ )..

u can use it like :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").css( { 'display' : 'none' } );
    $("#content").slideDown(1000);
  });
```

sipmle as that.

and i also agree with @Billy Moon , it can be a browser specific bug or u may be calling a page refresh command, somewhere within ur code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no problem inside. It's somewhere else in your code.

isn't that function call in some function that is called twice?